# How can I remove projects from the list of Recent Projects on Welcome to Pycharm dialog?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

When I start up PyCharm, it displays the list of recent projects. How can I remove a project from that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux:
1. Close PyCharm

2. Edit this file:

   ~/.PyCharm2017.2/config/options/recentProjectDirectories.xml
3. The recent file list looks like this:

   `<component name="RecentDirectoryProjectsManager">
   <option name="recentPaths">
     <list>
       <option value="$USER_HOME$/PycharmProjects/INTEG-1475" />
       <option value="$USER_HOME$/PycharmProjects/INTEG-6666" />
       <option value="$USER_HOME$/PycharmProjects/integ" />
       <option value="$USER_HOME$/PycharmProjects/scripts" />
       <option value="$USER_HOME$/dev/core-system" />
       <option value="$USER_HOME$/PycharmProjects/get-logs" />
     </list>`
4. Remove unwanted directories from the list
5. Save the file
6. Start PyCharm

Answer (score 4):

You can edit XML file `recentProjectDirectories.xml` located at C:\Users\< username >.PyCharm40\config\options.

Checked on Windows 7

Comment: I'm on Linux, so I cannot use your advice.

Comment: @AlexC Yes you can, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Click on the project in question and hit delete. If you want to clear the whole list, go to `File -> Reopen Project -> Clear List`.

Comment: In PyCharm 2017.2.x there is no such menu (Reopen Project). I don't see anything equivalent. Anyone? Thanks